# Deep-linking intent does not handle

Tags: android, deep-linking

My manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.dev.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Light" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.dev.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/links" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

I start my App (nominal mode) on MainActivity.

From a draft email (on my mobile of course), I click on this link: https://www.dev.com/links/123

The web navigator starts directly but my App never handles this link...

Do you have some investigation ways guys?

Comment: once try with exported flag true

Comment: Perfect it was this parameter! Thank you very much!